# How to prevent Angular CDK from adding transform property to element

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I'm using `Angular CDK` for Drag & Drop, the scenario is: When drag ends, I'm calculating new coords for the element and updating it, which causes DOM update as well

```
<div
  cdkDrag
  cdkDragBoundary=".page"
  [ngStyle]="position"
  (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event)"
>
  ...
</div>
```

And Typescript:

```
get position(): NotePositionEntry {
  return {
    top: `${this.note.posY}px`,
    left: `${this.note.posX}px`,
  } as NotePositionEntry;
}

dragEnded(dragEvent: any): void {
  this.note = {
    ...this.note,
    posX: this.note.posX + dragEvent.distance.x,
    posY: this.note.posY + dragEvent.distance.y,
  };
}
```

After method `dragEnded` sets `posX` and `posY`, `get position()` return new object, whcih should just set `css` `top` and `left` props.

**The problem is that, instead of `top` and `left`, I see `transform: translate3d(...)` property added to the element, which is causing issues (element is not positioned precisely).**

Any ideas, how can I prevent Angular CDK from adding `transform` property after drag ends?

Comment: Can't you use `CdkDropList`? [Demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/additional-samples/drag-drop)

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with CdkDrag where the host element was getting CSS style added to it:

```
transform: translate3d(x,y,z)
```

This happened only when I injected CdkDrag into the constructor of a custom directive that I used on the same element where I placed the cdkDrag attribute.

A solution that worked was to set style:

```
host:{ transform: none !important }
```

It feels like a hack. There should be a way to turn this off.